# C++ initialise nested class

Tags: c++, inner-classes

I'm currently struggling with initialising a nested class

```
class COuter
{
public:
   class CInner
    {
    public:
        ///Properties
        osMutexId mutex;
        CSingle_Element single_place[5];

        /// Methods
        CInner(const bool is_master, const uint32_t data_length);
    };
///inner Instance
CInner inner_obj;
}
```

The Constructor of CSingle_Element is defined as

```
CSingle_Element (const bool is_master, const uint32_t data_length)
```

How can I initialise the inner_obj?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an initializer list in the constructor:

```
COuter::CInner::CInner(const bool is_master, const uint32_t data_length) 
:mutex(0), 
single_place{
    {is_master, data_length}, 
    {is_master, data_length}, 
    {is_master, data_length}, 
    {is_master, data_length}, 
    {is_master, data_length}}
{}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/14be9645dbf34a36

It's worth noting that you almost never want an array as a member, especially if the array is of a type where you don't want to be using the default constructor. You probably want a `std::vector`.  Even if you think you want an array member, you usually really should be using `std::array<5, CSingle_Element>`. This requires an extra `{}` in the initializer list, but is otherwise pure-win.

Comment: hm can i use an iterator within the initialiser list? In this example the array length is 5. But let's say my array length is 100 than my init. list get's pretty long

Comment: @JuliusCaesar then you should probably use `std::vector`.